# Nokia X IAP not working on a real device

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, nokiax

I've already implemented **Nokia IAP** using an emulator and it was working fine. I could restore, get product details and upgrade fine. But seems like it's not working on a real device. Tried the code using RDA and also a real Nokia X device. My in-app product has a **Published** status. Here are what happens:

- When I use `getProductDetails()`, I'm getting a **bundle with size 1** (perhaps including only the **ERROR_CODE**), and an **error code 6**. It's happening with both my product ID and the test ID **1023608**. But using the emulator I'm successfully getting my product details.
- `getPurchases()` is working fine for me on the device.
- `getBuyIntent()` is also good on the real device but I can't purchase because my operator isn't allowed for IAP, which is not a problem.

**N.B.** I'm not using `setProductMappings()` method and I'm using the product ID alias which was set from **Nokia Publish**. Also I'm executing the methods inside **AsyncTask**. Can anyone please help me with why **getProductDetails()** is not working on a real device? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is following method returning?

int response = mService.isBillingSupported(3, getPackageName(), ITEM_TYPE_INAPP);

If it returns error code, you should not try to call other API methods. You should try with such operator SIM card that is supported.

Comment: It's returning 0. Which means billing is supported, right? Funny thing is, my logic is also not working for Nokia and my QA test is failing for this reason.

Comment: If you try pepperfarm sample and change productid to your own, it should work. If not then there is something else wrong.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. After updating the billing SDK, I can successfully restore/purchase/get details using the **test IDs**. But if I use my **textual product ID** to restore/get details, it returns **error code 6**. If I try to purchase, it shows error **Invalid product ID**. And if I use the **numeric product ID** to get details, I get a bundle looking like `{"isvalid":false,"productId":"*******"}`. But if I try to purchase using the **numeric ID**, it takes me to Checkout showing item name, price and buying option. These are happening on both emulator and remote device. Any idea? Thanks.